# IE Compatibility mode change using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ie-compatibility-mode

Hi my aspx page is having some third party controls and those are not appearing when I upgrade my IE version to 11. Till IE10 everything was worked fine.

And when I change my compatibility mode of my IE like this http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-enable-compatibility-view-in-internet-explorer-11-ie11/

my controls are working fine. But I cant ask my end user to do the same.

Is there any way to handle this?  I tried by adding below tag in  section of my page.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9"/>
```

But it is not working. Can some one tell me how to handle this through code?

Comment: can you be more specific about the problem? Which controls do not work?

Comment: peterblum calendar control

Comment: do you get errors in you error console?

Comment: No, I'm not getting any errors

Answer (score 1):

It's just `IE=9`, not `IE=EmulateIE9`:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
```

More here: [*How to Use X-UA-COMPATIBLE*](https://www.modern.ie/en-us/performance/how-to-use-x-ua-compatible).

---

Of course, I would also look at migrating to new or different controls that work properly with a modern engine. Quote from the article above:

> It is not a best practice to let issues like the example linger as your application is at risk of falling even further behind as web standards progress.